# Formatting "List of something" in accordance to KOMA script

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft, tocbasic

I am using `scrbook` document class.  I've created my own environment named `example` and I wanted to create "List of examples."  In that name I've loaded package `tocloft`.

However as much as I try, the "List of examples" is formatted differently than other lists, like "List of tables" or "List of figures": horizontal spacing is substantially smaller for "List of Examples".

I've tried everything, including option `titles`, which only makes things worse, changing vertical spacing.

Please help me format "List of examples" just like the other lists.

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,parskip=half,numbers=noenddot,bibliography=totoc,index=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,etoolbox}

% Adding option `titles' makes it worse
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listexamplename}{List of examples}
\newlistof[chapter]{example}{loe}{\listexamplename}
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\thechapter.\arabic{example}}
\newenvironment{example}[1]{\refstepcounter{example}\addcontentsline{loe}{example}{\protect\numberline{\theexample}{\ignorespaces #1}}\par\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Example\ \theexample:\ #1]}{\end{tcolorbox}}
% For list of examples, make space between chapters
\makeatletter
\preto\chapter{\addtocontents{loe}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\begin{example}{First example.}
\end{example}
\begin{table}
\caption{First graph.}
\end{table}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{example}{Second example.}
\end{example}
\begin{table}
\caption{Second graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{example}{Third example.}
\end{example}
\begin{table}
\caption{Third graph.}
\end{table}

\chapter{Lists}
\listoftables
\listofexample

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using the possibilities of package `tocbasic` which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. It is loaded by `scrbook` automatically.

```
\documentclass[11pt,parskip=half,numbers=noenddot,bibliography=totoc,index=totoc,
  listof=leveldown
]{scrbook}

\addtotoclist{loe}
\newcounter{example}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\thechapter.\arabic{example}}
\newcommand{\listofloename}{List of Examples}
\newcommand\listofexamples{\listoftoc{loe}}
\setuptoc{loe}{chapteratlist,leveldown}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@example{\l@figure}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{example}[1]{%
  \setlength\parfillskip{0pt plus 1fil}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    before title={%
      \refstepcounter{example}%
      \addxcontentsline{loe}{section}[\theexample]{\ignorespaces #1}},
    title=Example\ \theexample:\ \ignorespaces #1]%
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}

\begin{example}{First example.}
\end{example}
\begin{table}
\caption{First graph.}
\end{table}

\chapter{Second}
\begin{example}{Second example.}
\end{example}
\begin{table}
\caption{Second graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{example}{Third example.}
\end{example}
\begin{table}
\caption{Third graph.}
\end{table}

\chapter{Lists}
\listoftables
\listofexamples
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note: I have used the option `listof=leveldown` and `\setuptoc{loe}{leveldown}` to show both lists on one page. With this option they are sections. If they should be chapters simple remove this settings.

Comment: Thanks! This is working, all right.  I suggest that you remove `listof=leveldown` and `\setuptoc{loe}{chapteratlist,leveldown}`, or at least make a comment.  They are included into solution only to adapt to MWE, which uses `tocbasic`.  I have removed them for my use.

Comment: @Pymalion I have added a note regarding `leveldown`. But `\setuptoc{loe}{chapteratlist}` is used to insert the gap between the entries of different chapters in the list. (You have used `etoolbox` in your example to insert a similar gap). If there should be no gap in all lists use `chapteratlists=0pt` as class option.

Comment: Yes, right, I realised that now :)

Comment: +1: What I was looking for! Do you know how to add the custom list (Lost of Examples) to the TOC?

Comment: I think I found it in the manual: `\setuptoc{loe}{totoc}`